# JavaScript says array is empty even though there are strings in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of strings that I want to use. However, when I use the forEach function it runs 0 times. Also, when I print the size of the array, JS says that it is empty. But when I print the array in the console I can see that there are strings in it. What could be causing this?[image]

```js
import {drawKanji} from "../KanjiDrawing/kanji-painter-original";

require('../../css/kanji.css');

window.onload = addAllKanji;

var allSVGElements = [];

async function addAllKanji(){
    let fileNames = ["0f9a8","064e3","05ae1","05afa","062ac","062c8"];
    await fileNames.forEach(function (fileName) {
       fetchKanji(fileName);
    });
    addKanjiToHTML();
    drawKanji();
}

function fetchKanji(name){
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/public_html/static/kanjiSVG/${name}.svg`,{
        method: "GET",
    }).then(response => drawSVG(response))
        .catch(error => {
            throw error;
        });
}

async function drawSVG(svg) {
    let svgRawText = await svg.text();
    svgRawText = svgRawText.replace(/[\s\S]*(?=<svg)/,"");
    allSVGElements.push(svgRawText);
}

async function addKanjiToHTML() {
    console.log("length: "+allSVGElements.length);
    console.log(allSVGElements);
    console.log("length: "+allSVGElements.length);
    allSVGElements.forEach(function (ele) {
       console.log(ele);
       console.log("running forEach")
    });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `fetchKanji` await the `fetch` method? Otherwise you just fire a bunch of requests without waiting for the response to be processed, effectively drawing the SVGs before they are added to the array.

Comment: Along the same lines, you can't just `await` a `forEach`. Use something like `await Promise.all(fileNames.map(async function() { ... }));`

Comment: changing this does not seem to change the result.

Comment: `await fileNames.forEach` is that new syntax? looks wrong. You do realise, however, that `fetchKanji` doesn't return anything anyway - and `async function addKanjiToHTML` is pointless since there's no await and nothing asynchronous about that function

Comment: Thank you for your input. Incorrect usage of async functions and await is probably the problem. Any idea then how to do this? I want to get all the svg files and merge them into a single big string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using async/await incorrectly - see comments in code below

```
var allSVGElements = [];

async function addAllKanji(){
    let fileNames = ["0f9a8","064e3","05ae1","05afa","062ac","062c8"];
    // change to Promise.all
    return await Promise.all(fileNames.map(function (fileName) {
        // return something
        return fetchKanji(fileName);
    }));
}

function fetchKanji(name){
    // return the promise
    return fetch(`http://localhost:8080/public_html/static/kanjiSVG/${name}.svg`,{
        method: "GET",
    }).then(response => drawSVG(response))
        .catch(error => {
            throw error;
        });
}

async function drawSVG(svg) {
    let svgRawText = await svg.text();
    svgRawText = svgRawText.replace(/[\s\S]*(?=<svg)/,"");
    allSVGElements.push(svgRawText);
}

//doesn't need to be async
function addKanjiToHTML() {
    console.log("length: "+allSVGElements.length);
    console.log(allSVGElements);
    console.log("length: "+allSVGElements.length);
    allSVGElements.forEach(function (ele) {
       console.log(ele);
       console.log("running forEach")
    });
}
```

though a more concise and better written version of your code would be

```
function addAllKanji() {
    let fileNames = ["0f9a8","064e3","05ae1","05afa","062ac","062c8"];
    return Promise.all(fileNames.map(fetchKanji));
}

function fetchKanji(name){
    // return the promise
    return fetch(`http://localhost:8080/public_html/static/kanjiSVG/${name}.svg`, {method: "GET"}).then(drawSVG)
}

async function drawSVG(svg) {
    let svgRawText = await svg.text();
    return svgRawText.replace(/[\s\S]*(?=<svg)/,"");
}

addAllKanji().then(allSVGElements => {
    console.log("length: "+allSVGElements.length);
    console.log(allSVGElements);
    console.log("length: "+allSVGElements.length);
    allSVGElements.forEach(function (ele) {
       console.log(ele);
       console.log("running forEach")
    });
});
```

this even includes the functionality of `addKanjiToHTML` at the end

---

to be honest, I think this is a case where async/await is not giving you any advantage

I'd have written the above code like

```
let fetchKanji = name => fetch(`http://localhost:8080/public_html/static/kanjiSVG/${name}.svg`, {method: "GET"})
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(svgRawText => svgRawText.replace(/[\s\S]*(?=<svg)/,""));

function addAllKanji() {
    let fileNames = ["0f9a8","064e3","05ae1","05afa","062ac","062c8"];
    return Promise.all(fileNames.map(fetchKanji));
}


addAllKanji().then(allSVGElements => {
    console.log("length: "+allSVGElements.length);
    console.log(allSVGElements);
    console.log("length: "+allSVGElements.length);
    allSVGElements.forEach(ele => {
       console.log(ele);
       console.log("running forEach")
    });
});
```

not an async/await in sight :p

Though some people find

```
let fetchKanji = async (name) => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/public_html/static/kanjiSVG/${name}.svg`, {method: "GET"});
    const svgRawText = await response.text();
    return svgRawText.replace(/[\s\S]*(?=<svg)/,"");
};
```

easier to read

Comment: thank you that did the trick. Coming from offline app programming the whole async concept is quite hard to grasp.

Comment: @NikolajBjerregaard - I've just added a third alternative - to be honest, I think trying to use async/await (which is syntax sugar for promises) in this case has actually made your code more complex - though that's just my opinion :p

Comment: Ah i see, i just really like await because it feels like synchronous programming, it does not continue before the task is complete. My go-to method is just to try to await everything that i think might be async. But as shown here that is not a very good way to do things...

Comment: well, I did add yet another alternative :p

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea.

`let` & `await` only works inside the `async function`. It doesn't work for global functions, it means they don't have access to global functions like "fetchKanji(name)". Fix this and try.

Answer (score -2):

if you run the below code that is working fine.

```
let fileNames = ["0f9a8","064e3","05ae1","05afa","062ac","062c8"];
    await fileNames.forEach(function (fileName) {
       console.log(fileName);
    });
```